# Stability of benzyl free radical hyperconjugated with a methyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, stability

[image]

In this picture, which one is more stable?

> My teacher says the second one as it has 4 alpha-Hydrogen whereas in the first picture the free-radical carbon has only 1 alpha-Hydrogen. That's why second compound is more stable than the first one.

> But I am not convinced. My intuition says me that the benzene ring will provide more stability in the first compound compared to the stability of the second one.

What do you think of my proposed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for the top radical being more stable. The hyperconjugation to the hydrogens and the C-C bond will have a very small effect when compared with the resonance delocalization of the radical into the benzene ring.

[image: The resonance in the benzylic radical]

Sadly I think your chemistry teacher is wrong.

Comment: I agree. The benzylic radical is by far the more stable